# How to make AJAX calls with Dynamic URLS in HDIV

Tags: hdiv

When I make dynamic URLS in AJAX calls (based on some field value) then how to make HDIV work with this? Since the URL is dynamic HDIV won't know about this URL on server side. This would fail ultimately. Also we couldn't add it to exceptions. Then how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are some options:

- Render all possible links, with all possible parameter values. Keep them hidden and choice the right one by JavaScript before submit.
- Use a form instead of a link. You can create a hidden form and add multivalue parameters as select fields. Select the right values by JavaScript before submitting the form.
- If the previous options are too complex, define the parameter as a startParameters. But note that it will not be validated.